# Outlook is automatically open when open word in powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, ms-word, com

When I open a word document by powershell, I realized that outlook is also opened in background when checking with Task manager. Is there anyway to prevent this since it affects to my script performance. Im using office 2016.

My script:

```
$word = New-object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = false
$word.Documents.Open("myFile")
```

Comment: Does it happen when you open the application (ie. is `$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application` enough to reproduce the issue), or does it only happen when you open a document? If only after opening a document: does is happen with _any document_, or only certain ones?

Comment: It happened after word file is opened, and happened with all types of word documents (docx, docm)

Comment: Could be an Addin. Check what you have installed from Word: File > Options > Addins

Comment: @LongThái, have you ever sorted this out?

Comment: Also take care, `false` is not a Powershell boolean. It has to be `$False`.

Answer (score 0):

Word does not open Outlook by itself. You can have Office installations without Outlook.

Most likely this happens because of some third-party addin that creates an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object.

Look at the list of installed Word addins (File | Options | Addins) and disable them to figure out which one causes this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found it out:

```
$word.Documents.Open("myFile")
```

...returns the document object, and when that object is returned to stdout (i.e. "dumped to the console"), somehow sometimes Outlook starts.

As a bit of a proof:

```
$word = New-object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $True
$word.Documents.Add()
```

When running that, Outlook fires up after entering the third line and before the return value of `Add()` gets dumped onto the PS console.

When I replace the third line with...

```
$document = $word.Documents.Add()
```

...Outlook doesn't get started. When I then just type `$Document`<kbd>Enter</kbd> to dump the variable to the PS console, Outlook gets started.

So, at least in my case, not Word itself has been the culprit but dumping the document object to the PS console.